# Python: How to multiply elements from one array with column/row from another

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do some analysis on a large dataset using NumPy.

I have:

1. One 50X1 Matrix (eigenvalues)
2. One 50x50 Matrix (eigenvectors)

I need to be able to take each element of the eigenvalue matrix
and multiply by column corresponding to the eigenvector.

So, multiply i-th element of array one, by i-th column of array 2, and so on for all i's.

Any ideas? :/

Comment: Maybe use numpy's `multiply`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the numpy [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
n = 4
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(n,n))
B = np.array([1,0,2, 0])
B = B.reshape((1,n))
C = B * A
```

The multiplication is between a (1, n) and (n, n) matrix.
To satisfy the broadcasting rule, the B matrix will be "extended" to a (n, n)
array before the multiplication, which is then performed element-by-element as usual.

The above multiplication is equivalent to

```
BB = np.array([[1,0,2, 0],
               [1,0,2, 0],
               [1,0,2, 0],
               [1,0,2, 0]])
C = BB * A
```

but you never have to construct the matrix `BB` in memory.

**Edit: Benchmarks**

Since using a diagonal matrix might seem easier to read, I present the following quick benchmark you can try yourself.

```
# Setup data
n = 50
A = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
B = np.random.normal(size=n)
B1 = B.reshape(1, 3)

# Make sure results are the same
C = np.dot(A, np.diag(B))
C1 = B1 * A
print np.allclose(C, C1) # Should be 'True'

# Bench with IPython
>>> %timeit np.dot(A, np.diag(B))
The slowest run took 7.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.7 µs per loop

>>> %timeit B1 * A
The slowest run took 10.27 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.64 µs per loop
```

I.e. for a 50x50 matrix, using broadcasting is in the order of 6 times as fast as using `np.diag` and matrix multiplication.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand whats happening in your example. 

I'm not interested in the *matrix* multiplication between the two arrays but 

the product of *each* element in the 50x1 matrix, with 1 column and 1 column only in the 50x50 array 

Is there a way to call each element in the 50x1 array? A way to call each column in the second array? If so, I could then use a simple loop to sum all such products up?

Comment: I think the examples in the documentation I included in my answer is pretty good. Basically it is a feature where numpy will extend your arrays to fit the expression, if the broadcasting rules are held. It does this without copying the actual array, which means it is quite fast.

Comment: I have extended my answer somewhat

Answer (score 1):

First convert 1-dim eigenvalue vector into diagonal matrix.
Then, apply matrix multiplication.

```
import numpy as np
eigenval_diag = np.diag(eigenvalue_vec) # 50x50 matrix
result = eigenval_diag * eigen_matrix # 50x50 matrix
```

Comment: Just a note, this is a lot slower than using broadcasting (see my answer) since it both needs to create the diagonal matrix in memory, and also perform matrix multiplication. It *is* a good, correct and very readable answer though.

Comment: The `*` in `eigenval_diag * eigen_matrix` IS NOT the matrix multiplication operator.  If you use `np.dot` or the new `@` operator, then you have a further problem, because premultiplying a generic matrix by a diagonal matrix you are multiplying the *rows* of the matrix by the corresponding diagonal elements, while the OP asks for column multiplication.